# How can I pass the values to previous screen in jet pack compose modalBottomSheet

Tags: android, navigation, android-jetpack-compose

I have a jetpack compose screen. When I click on the button the modalBottomSheet is opened. When I click on a button in the modalBottomSheet I want to collapse the bottom sheet and pass some values to previous screen. How can I do that?

Comment: Please include your code. How are you implementing your 'previous screen'? How are you creating your modal bottom sheet?

Answer (score 0):

Utilize a lambda that you call/pass the values into when the button is clicked.
With Compose data flows down and events flow up. And those events are usually in the form of lambdas.